# How can I print the same value that I generated using array_rand() after using it?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this (except that it has a lot more keys):

```
$passwords = array("key1","key2","key3");
```

To get a random key from the array, I've done this:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($passwords); 
$rand_key  = $passwords[$rand_keys];
```

Now I use `$rand_key` to try to log the user in. What I want to do is to check if the password worked and if it did, echo "success: [password]". I'm worried that doing `echo "Success: $rand_key";` will just print a random key from the array instead of printing the one that was successful.

What can I do to print the key that was successful instead of another random one? I thought of using sessions, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Uh, why don't you just set it to a variable?

Comment: You seem to have superstitious believes about how PHP works. Your `$rand_keys` variable holds the randomly chosen key. It's not going to change unless you change it. You can use it as many times as you want.

Comment: @deceze Maybe OP is not superstitious but only a little stitious =)

Comment: Try not to take the downvotes too personally.  This is not an awful question.  Folks here on Stack Overflow will be honest and direct (sometimes tersely so) with you, but they will hopefully not be rude.  Your question did get some extra negative attention because you "vandalized" your post (removing all the content), which is against the rules of the site.  It looks like you've gotten a good, clear answer from David.  I would just move on, and if you have more questions - ask them!  Just be careful not to break the rules, or take things too personally.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm worried that doing echo "Success: $rand_key"; will just print a random key from the array instead of printing the one that was successful.

Nope, it'll print whatever that variable holds.  When you do this:

```
$rand_key  = $passwords[$rand_keys];
```

The `$rand_key` variable doesn't hold a reference to the notion of `$passwords[$rand_keys]`, it holds the actual value resulting from having executed `$passwords[$rand_keys]` once.  Re-using the `$rand_key` variable won't execute `$passwords[$rand_keys]` again, it'll just continue to hold the value from that first and only execution.

Similarly, `$rand_keys = array_rand($passwords);` results in executing `array_rand($passwords)` *once* and storing the result in `$rand_keys`, so that result won't change when `$rand_keys` is referenced again.

> What can I do to print the key that was successful instead of another random one? I thought of using sessions, but I'm not sure.

Ah, are you trying to persist the value across multiple executions of the script?  That's another issue entirely, and you're probably correct that `$_SESSION` would be useful here.  Any persistence medium outside of the code will work, depending on where you want the value stored.  It's *likely* that session state is what you want here.  In that case, when the script first runs you would persist your value in session state:

```
$_SESSION['rand_key'] = $rand_key;
```

Then when the script executes again, you'd retrieve that value:

```
$rand_key = $_SESSION['rand_key'];
```

Since it's the same script running multiple times, naturally you'd want to do some state checking to determine if it's the first or second time it's run.  After all, the script doesn't innately *know* if it's been called before or not, it just executes the code as-is.  A simple way to check for this could be just to see if that session value exists:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['rand_key']) {
    // there's a session value in place, the random key has been generated already
} else {
    // the random key hasn't previously been generated
}
```